# How to use AndroidSDK backup instead of downloading it again?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have reinstalled Windows 10 and I want to use AndroidSDK folder instead of downloading it again? How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do nothing!
SDK has no need to install.

Just give old SDK path to android studio.

To change SDK path in windows, press ctrl+shift+alt+s which will open project properties where you can find first option named SDK Location click on it and there you can change SDK path, JDK path and NDK path also.

Comment: At the screen I posted I didn't find a way to not download SDK, but later I changed path manually.